# Is $g(x,y) = f(\frac{x}{2},\frac{y}{2})$ correct notation?

Tags: functions, notation

I was a bit confused when I saw this statement $g(x,y) = 2f(\frac{x}{2},\frac{y}{2})$, and seeing it used in a double integral $\int \int g(x,y) = 2 \int \int f(\frac{x}{2},\frac{x}{2}) \, dx dy$.

I understand that idea is for us to use the change of variables $u = \frac{x}{2}$ and $v = \frac{y}{2}$. However, is $f(\frac{x}{2},\frac{y}{2})$ proper notation?

Comment: It all depends, of course, on how $\;f,g\; $ are defined and the relation between them.

Comment: Sure, $g(x,y)=2f(x/2,y/2)$ is perfectly fine notationally.

Comment: A bit sloppy, though. I think this what you meant: $\iint g(x,y)\,dx\,dy = 2 \iint f(x/2,y/2)\,2.d(x/2)\,2.d(y/2) = 8 \iint f(u,v)\,du\,dv$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any function $g \colon {\mathbb R}^2 \to {\mathbb R}$, you can define another function $f \colon {\mathbb R}^2 \to {\mathbb R}$ such that $g(x,y) = 2 f(\frac{x}{2}, \frac{y}{2})$ for all $x, y \in {\mathbb R}$. Just define $f(x, y) := \frac{1}{2} g(2x, 2y)$ for all $x, y \in {\mathbb R}$.

With that definition $\int\!\!\int g(x,y) \, dx dy = \int\!\!\int 2 f(\frac{x}{2}, \frac{y}{2}) \, dx dy = 2 \int\!\!\int f(\frac{x}{2}, \frac{y}{2})\, dx dy$. Changing variables as you indicated ($x = 2u$, $y = 2v$) then gives that this is equal to $2 \int\!\!\int f(u,v) \,2 du \,2 dv = 8 \int\!\!\int f(u,v) \,du dv$.